# Sqlalchemy enumeration/type matching?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

how do i do enumeration in sqlachemy?  im using pylons if it matters.  i also want to have in code to create different object depends on the enumeration, with the same parameters, but different object class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy 0.6 has [generic `Enum` column type](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum), earlier versions have vendor specific types for some database drivers. And sure, you can use `Integer`.

Initializing different classes based based on column value is easy. What you need for this particular case is [single table inheritance](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#single-table-inheritance).